# Delete folder locally but keep remotely

Tags: git

I have a folder containing some code that will be required by anyone downloading my repository to their computer, but isn't needed by me. Let's call it `foo`.

I want to be able to delete `foo` from my local system, but not from the remote repository. I obviously cannot add it to `.gitignore` because it has already been tracked.

Is this possible with Git? If so, how can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious about your use case. Why did you need to delete this folder locally? What harm was it doing by being around?

Comment: @MarkAmery The folder contained a python module that I needed when editing off different computers without said module installed. The IDE I was using on my main computer didn't like having the same module installed twice, so I thought it easier to simply remove the folder from my local system. I'm sure there was a better way to fix it, but this seemed like the most straight-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark the files with assume unchanged and then delete them. From this point on git will ignore any changes made to those files.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

## ***`--assume-unchanged`***

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <path>
```

In case you need to print out list of files marked with the `--assume-unchanged` flag:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

---

[image]

Comment: As a side note, if you are using egit with Eclipse, right clicking on a file/folder and doing Team>>Advanced>>Assume-unchanged does the same thing